# How do I change the text alignment in iOS select menus?

Tags: ios, css

By default `iOS` select menus appear to centre all the items, however on this site, they have managed to align all the text to the left.

[Euro 2016 The complete guide to every squad and every player](http://www.theguardian.com/football/ng-interactive/2016/jun/01/euro-2016-the-complete-guide-to-every-squad-and-every-player-in-france)

Is it possible to achieve the same thing with `CSS`?

Here's an image showing what they have done.

[image]

Comment: Look at the styles they used. and where is your code?